# How to manage permissions on RESTful APIs

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mean-stack

I'm writing a MEAN.JS multiusers application and some actions must be restricted so I'm trying to find the **"Best Practices"** to manage permissions in my own APIs

I'm thinking about setting an array of permissions on every user and every API must check if the requiring user has all the permissions needed.

ex.

```
 GET /api/foo/:foo would need "foo-read"
 POST /api/foo would need "foo-create"
 PUT /api/foo/:foo would need "foo-update"
 DELETE /api/foo/:foo would need "foo-delete"

 GET /api/foo/:foo/bar:/bar would need "foo-read" and "bar-read"
 POST /api/foo/bar would need "foo-create" and "bar-create"
 PUT /api/foo/:foo/bar:/bar would need "foo-update" and "bar-update"
 DELETE /api/foo/:foo/bar:/bar would need "foo-delete" and "bar-delete"
```

This way a user can have the permission to create new users but not the permission to give them administration rights.

I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this or if there are some existing middelware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an authorization framework. I use [cansecurity](https://github.com/deitch/cansecurity) (full disclosure: I am the original author). It supports using both programmatic middleware and declarative formats.

I would use the declarative for this, because I like keeping my server.js clean, and all of my security config in one place:

```
{
    "routes": [
        // [verb,path,default,[test params,] test condition]
        ["GET","/api/foo/:foo","item.roles.foo_read === true"],
        ["PUT","/api/foo/:foo","item.roles.foo_update === true"]
    ]   
}
```

Comment: can I use cansecurity with PassportJS ?

Comment: I haven't tried it. I guess you mean to use passport for authentication and cansec for authorization? I don't see why it wouldn't, but I have never tried. If you can whip up a use case as to how it would work together (gist?), I can see if it is integratable.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do it using express middleware filters.

```
app.get(function(req,res,next){your code - res.end(data);});
```

to

```
var checkpermissions=function(req,res,next){ if bad permission raise error or print access denied page otherwise run next();};
app.get(checkpermissions,function(req,res,next){your code - res.end(data);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm convinced that the access control mustn't depend on the REST API. REST is just a delivery method, which details can change very fast and which is not the only single delivery method, e.g. I can create a traditional HTML web application as delivery method as well. The authorization must depend on the business logic or in other words domain model. So in your case the authorization must be between the REST API and the business logic and it must be described with business terms, not with REST terms. Handling this on client side is very easy, because the server will send back only the allowed links with each response, so you have nothing to do in the client side code. Now if you have spaghetti code on server side, then you have a problem...

Comment: If I open my APIs to third party I can't rely on them to apply my business logic

Comment: @Edo I don't understand what you are talking about, but I guess you don't understand either what I wrote.

Comment: it's perfectly plausible but as long as your answer isn't useful to me I downvoted it but thanks anyway for your effort

Comment: @Edo Np. I started with your approach either, it took me about a months to think the whole topic over. Good luck!

Comment: I do think that including the REST API  in the permission level makes sense, as long as you have it done properly. Even if you have the same API with multiple users, you may want to specify roles to the users, and allow or not them to access a specific endpoint. Doing it like this can be done in only one place. for all API